# Tidying dataframe with one parameter per row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe like this:

```
d = {'Date': ['2020-10-09', '2020-10-09', '2020-10-09', '2020-10-10', '2020-10-10', '2020-10-10', '2020-10-11', '2020-10-11', '2020-10-11'],
     'ID': ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T1', 'T2', 'T3','T1', 'T2', 'T3'],
     'Value': [13, 12, 11, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22]}
     
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    Date    ID  Value
0   2020-10-09  T1  13
1   2020-10-09  T2  12
2   2020-10-09  T3  11
3   2020-10-10  T1  14
4   2020-10-10  T2  15
5   2020-10-10  T3  16
6   2020-10-11  T1  20
7   2020-10-11  T2  21
8   2020-10-11  T3  22
```

And I'm trying to get:

```
d = {'Date': ['2020-10-09', '2020-10-10', '2020-10-11'],
     'Value T1': ['13', '14', '20'],
     'Value T2': ['12', '15', '21'],
     'Value T3': ['11', '15', '22']}
     
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df


Date            Value T1    Value T2    Value T3
0   2020-10-09        13          12          11
1   2020-10-10        14          15          15
2   2020-10-11        20          21          22
```

I tried with pivot but I got the error:
"Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.pivot_table` like shown below,

```
pdf = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    values=['Value'],
    index=['Date'],
    columns=['ID'],
    aggfunc='first'
).reset_index(drop=False)

pdf.columns = ['Date', "Value T1", "Value T2", "Value T3"]


    Date    Value T1    Value T2    Value T3
0   2020-10-09  13  12  11
1   2020-10-10  14  15  16
2   2020-10-11  20  21  22
```

Note that aggfunc is first here. Which means if there is multiple values for a given ID at given Date, You'll get the first value in the dataframe. You can change it to min/max/last as per you need